# WPF Ribbon - Hide quick access toolbar

Tags: wpf, ribbon

how do you hide Quick Access Toolbar in a WPF's Ribbon?

Comment: Do you want there to never be a Quick Access Toolbar, or are you looking for show/hide functionality? I'm using the Microsoft Ribbon, and I have no buttons in my QAT by default and nothing shows up there.

Comment: I want to permanently hide it. That's probably because you use RibbonWindow and I use normal Windows, because RibbonWindow looks like a piece of s.. in Win XP.

Comment: Gotchya... I do use RibbonWindow. And I agree... looks terrible in XP.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Quick Access Toolbar is automatically hidden when the Ribbon control is in a RibbonWindow. When it is not, it seems impossible to hide it. I have already worked hours on this issue and was unable to hide it properly.
But there is one simple workaround: Place the Ribbon control inside of a Panel and give it a negative top margin so it will slide outside of the Panel. Set the Panel's ClipToBounds property to true and the QAT will be hidden.
By the way - there are multiple Ribbon implementations for WPF, even by Microsoft themselves ("[Fluent Ribbon](http://fluent.codeplex.com/)" and "Microsoft Ribbon for WPF"), so next time you should mention which one you are talking about.

Comment: It's WPF Ribbon preview from http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Ribbon%20Preview

Comment: Just a note if you started with a stock RibbonWindow as I did: I changed the window type to Window in both XAML and code-behind, added ClipToBounds="true" to the LayoutRoot grid, and gave the ribbon a top margin of -22.

Comment: @Sean yeah, the value of -22 seems to be the right one.

Answer (score 44):

For [Microsoft Ribbon for WPF](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11877), you can hide it by using the `VisualTreeHelper`. On the `Loaded` event handler, just resize the row containing the Quick Access Toolbar to 0 :

```
private void RibbonLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Grid child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild((DependencyObject)sender, 0) as Grid;
  if (child != null)
  {
    child.RowDefinitions[0].Height = new GridLength(0);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Too bad it doesn't fix the designer window, but I can live with it. Beats out the other solutions here

Comment: Your answer doesn't work for me. Btw, in my case the ribbon is inside a grid.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want it all in the XAML, this works

```
<ribbon:Ribbon>
    <ribbon:Ribbon.Loaded>CollapseQuickAccessToolbar</ribbon:Ribbon.Loaded>
    <x:Code>
        private void CollapseQuickAccessToolbar(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            ((Grid)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild((DependencyObject)sender, 0)).RowDefinitions[0].Height = new GridLength(0);
        }
    </x:Code>
</ribbon:Ribbon>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

```
this.ribbonControl1.ToolbarLocation = DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonQuickAccessToolbarLocation.Hidden;
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old post, but found an easier solution...
Add this inside the ribbon :-

```
<ribbon:Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
    <ribbon:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</ribbon:Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  Is there something else that needs done?

Comment: @psubsee2003 : By setting this property, I was able to hide the tool bar. I also set the context menu to "{x:Null}" at ribbon, button group and button levels to disable the context menu.

Answer (score -1):

Bit late to the party.

```
<my:Ribbon   >
            <my:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu >
                <my:RibbonApplicationMenu Visibility="Collapsed">
                </my:RibbonApplicationMenu>
            </my:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
```

This will help to hide the quick bar

Comment: The question was regarding Quick Access Toolbar, not the Application Menu. And no, collapsing Application Menu does not hide the Quick Access Toolbar.