# Customize WPF Ribbon

Tags: wpf, customization, ribbon, ribboncontrolslibrary

I want to customize normal WPF Ribbon layout.
As shown below I want to remove the command area of ribbon control.

[image]

Please suggest any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265392/wpf-ribbon-hide-quick-access-toolbar)

```
    void ribbon_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild((DependencyObject)sender, 0) as Grid;
        if (child != null)
        {
            child.RowDefinitions[0].Height = new GridLength(0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the Quick Access Toolbar spacing you can change the main window to be a [`RibbonWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonwindow?view=netframework-4.7.2).  This will move the Quick Access Toolbar to the top title bar.  If there are no items, it will be hidden.

XAML:

```
<ribbon1:RibbonWindow x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
   xmlns:ribbon1="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;
      assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon"
   ...
```

Codebehind:

```
namespace Example
{
   public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow
   {
      ...
```